# Add helmet to nextjs middleware

Tags: next.js, helmet.js, next-connect

I have a full-stack nextjs application and I want to add helmet for having secure headers.
I try to use 'next-connect' package but helmet won't add new headers to response headers.
(I am using nextjs13 with 'pages' routes)
middleware.ts:

```
import {
  NextResponse,
  type NextRequest,
  type NextFetchEvent,
} from "next/server";
import { createEdgeRouter } from "next-connect";
import helmet from "helmet";
const router = createEdgeRouter<NextRequest, NextFetchEvent>();
router.use(async (req, event, next) => {
  helmet(); //will not add any new header to response 
  return next();
});
router.all(() => {
  // default if none of the above matches
  return NextResponse.next(); //continue to next middleware
});
export function middleware(req: NextRequest, event: NextFetchEvent) {
  return router.run(req, event);
}
export const config = {
  matcher: "/api/:path*", //apply this middleware to /api routes
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `next-connect`'s Express wrapper.

```
router.use(expressWrapper(helmet()));
```